# Generating XML Resources into Classpath using Annotation Processors

Tags: annotation-processing

I am currently working on a Gradle 3.3 project in Intellij 15.0.6.

I am using the [Gradle APT plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin) to add annotation processors to my classpath.

It works fine when generating Java class files, however I need to be able to generate XML sources within the `resources` directory equivalent in the build directory's generated directory.

Here is my build directory structure currently:

[Project Build Directory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt20p.png)

As you can see, it does not include a `resources` directory, which I suspect is what may be causing this problem.

The current exception I receive from running my annotation processor via `./gradlew assemble` is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource creation not supported in location CLASS_PATH`

The code I am using within my annotation processor to generate the xml file:

`FileObject source = processingEnv.getFiler()
.createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, "", "ap-test-2.html");`

**Note: I used an HTML extension just as a test, XML should produce the same results.**

`javax.tools.StandardLocation` has other output locations as well:

The `SOURCE_OUTPUT` location worked to place the XML within the same package as the generated Java classes, within `src/apt/main`. This is not my desired behaviour however. I need them to reside within the classpath.

I have not found this exception discussed anywhere else after extensive research.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH` is only for input, not output. The only output locations are `SOURCE_OUPUT` (the `build/generated/source/apt/…` folder), `CLASS_OUTPUT` (the standard Gradle `build/classes/…`), and `NATIVE_HEADER_OUPUT`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardLocation.html

JavaC has no notion of classes vs. resources outputs, but if you run your annotation processor during your compilation then `CLASS_OUTPUT` should work (Gradle should then copy everything into the final directory/JAR). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting, Intellij separates the `build` classpath files into two directories: `classes` and `resources`. My processor added the HTML to the `classes` directory after changing the location to `CLASS_OUTPUT`. I will test this further and let you know what I find.

Comment: It seems Intellij merges those two directories together and adds them to the classpath, so setting the location to `CLASS_OUTPUT` should work theoretically. I'll try to get an MVP working with my processor to verify that this is the case.